# Sending email on Internal Server Error

Tags: java, jsf, jboss, error-handling

Hello I searched the net, but I haven't found a solution to my problem,

I have a `Jboss AS6 server` and `JSF Application` running on it.

The application is *buggy* and there are sometimes "`http 500, internal server errors`"

**Now my Question:**
1) Is it possible to redirect to a *custom page*, when `http 500` arrives?

2) Is it possible to send an `email` with the *stacktrace of the error*? 
(I have absolutely no Idea how to do it, the stacktrace of the error is shown at the client `webbrowser`, but that is exactly I don't want).

Answer (score 0):

1) Code 500 means "Internal Error" => exception has occurred. You can define a global error page in web.xml like this

```
<error-page> 
    <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type> 
    <location>/generalError.jsp</location> 
</error-page>
```

where generalError.jsp is your error page.

2) There are two options - include code in the JSP that sends an email via JavaMail API (example can be found [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_sending_email.htm)) or create a SMTP appender for log4j (example can be found [here](https://community.jboss.org/thread/161516)), however you have to use JBoss at least 6.1.0 because there is a [bug](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBAS-8791) in previous 6.x.x versions of JBoss AS.